# "Copy Formula From Above" when inconsistent come out

Tags: excel, vba

I want excel to copy automatically, if it finds inconsistent cells

```
Sub IGNOREINCONSISTENT()
Dim r As Range: Set r = Range("Your Range")
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In r
    cel.Errors(xlInconsistentFormula).ignore = True
Next cel
End Sub
```

This is the code i found in forum but for ignore not

[image: Copy Formula from above]

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim FRange As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A10")
    
    '~~> Work with only those cells which have formula
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FRange = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '~~> Check if there are cells which have formula
    If FRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells with formula found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Filldown on cells which have Inconsistent Formula
    For Each aCell In FRange
        '~~> .FillDown in a single cell will pull the formula down.
        '~~> Just like when you press Ctrl + D
        If aCell.Errors.Item(xlInconsistentFormula).Value = True _
        Then aCell.FillDown
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]